# msmq non-transactional messages duplicate/wrong ordered

Tags: msmq, duplicate-data

can you help me with scenarios which can lead to ***non-transactional*** messages to be duplicated/wrong ordered. as far as i understand it can be:

- result of routing problems
- restart of sender/receiver MSMQ service(or computer)
- sender/receiver is temporary not available in the network
- computer quota reached
- queue quota cant be the reason, right?
- restart computer/service/application when reading from incoming queue (?)
- when i read from non-transactional queue, can i read message arrived later before earlier message?

Can you correct me if i'm wrong and add something to my list?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Duplication can happen if data is sent twice for some reason. Proposed scenarios are mainly related to network issues (where the message is sent down multiple routes because of network errors but more than one copy of the message eventually arrive, or handshaking packet loss forces the sender to resend).

Restarting the MSMQ service in a manner that means it doesn't get to shut down cleanly first (such as power outage or BSOD) may potentially cause duplication through packet loss - data being received by the hardware but not yet processed by the software being lost through the restart.

Normal operation, such as quotas being exceeded, shouldn't cause duplication problems. Nor should absence of sender or receiver on the network as MSMQ is an asynchronous product which is designed to expects machines to not always be available.

Non-transactional messages being out of order, although rare, is perfectly normal and should be expected. You should never design a non-transactional system that relies on messages arriving in a queue in the same order that they were sent in. Only transactional messages sent within the same single transaction will arrive in the same order as they were sent. This is not the same as sending multiple independent transactional messages were order is not guaranteed.

Note that MSMQ has built-in duplicate detection. If you have a problem with duplicate messages, you may just need to tweak detection parameters. [How MSMQ prevents duplicate messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/04/02/how-msmq-prevents-duplicate-messages.aspx)

Comment: thank you very much John for your answer. i have not duplicate/order problems YET, due to we use transactionl queues by now. we just try to realize what may be a consequences move to non-transactional queues because we have a perfomance problems. thanks for the aricle you refence, i read it before. according to "...The cache is stored in memory and is reset if you restart the computer..." so restart still can be a reason for problem. speacking of quotas - when a computer quota is reached messages will return the outgoing queue. can't M2 be sent before M1 receives ack?

Comment: You could try a test like: (1) set queue quota to 1MB; (2) send 2MB message; (3) send 1KB message. Does the small message get past the large message or does the large message block all messages behind it?